# How to filter and get an "object" instead of a "quesryset" in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

I am trying to filter the users by passing the **email_id** through URL by passing email_id and getting that particular user. I tried doing this using **django-filters** but I got a queryset with one object inside it but instead I need the object itself.

here's the model -

```
class User(models.Model):
    """This is the Users model where all users data will be saved"""
    first_name    = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name     = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email_id      = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default="")
    city          = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    state         = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    country       = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    zip_code      = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    birthdate     = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo_url     = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    gender        = models.ForeignKey(Gender, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, 
    related_name='user_gender')
    joined        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

I tried using this viewset but it gives me a queryset instead of an object and I coudn't put my mind around on it.

```
class UserFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta: 
        model = User
        fields = {
            'email_id': ['iexact']
        }

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = UserFilter
```

This is the url I am currently passing -

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/?email_id__iexact=somemail@gmail.com
```

This is the JSON I'm getting -

```
[
    {
        "id": 26,
        "first_name": "Sarthak",
        "last_name": "Rohatgi",
        "email_id": "sarthak@gmail.com",
        "city": "city",
        "state": "state",
        "country": "India",
        "zip_code": "000000",
        "mobile_number": "9876543210",
        "birthdate": "2001-01-00",
        "photo_url": "",
        "gender": {
            "gender": "Male"
        }
    }
]
```

This is the JSON that I want -

```
{
    "id": 26,
    "first_name": "Sarthak",
    "last_name": "Rohatgi",
    "email_id": "sarthak@gmail.com",
    "city": "city",
    "state": "state",
    "country": "India",
    "zip_code": "000000",
    "mobile_number": "9876543210",
    "birthdate": "2001-01-00",
    "photo_url": "",
    "gender": {
        "gender": "Male"
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use renderers for that https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/

Comment: You should use the detail view.

Comment: @PriyanshuJain I apologise but I am a beginner and did not understand it. Can you provide me some reference to learn about them or perhaps maybe explain yourself about it?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Can you show me the way on how can I use it. I was able to successfully do it using primary key which is my id but I was not able to do it using email_id

Comment: @Sarthak I suppose you are building rest APIs. So if you use django rest framework and add custom renderer class to your view you will be able to control response. Try reading django rest framework docs(https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#example) or look for drf tutorials on youtube .https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-InaSDmAlOU

Comment: Hi, I think that different serializer might solve your problem. Can you share with us the JSON output from your endpoint?

Comment: @YvesHaryI added the JSON response.

Comment: @PriyanshuJain I tried using drf renderers but I was unsuccessful to achieve the result. Could you help me some more?

Comment: @Sarthak Inside renderer can you check if length of data is one then return first item.